# Hide or Show Transfer Icon

Tags: html, angular, typescript, scss-lint

I am trying to Hide **Transfer Button** If an account is a negative value or Show  Transfer if an account is a positive value.

I want to check if the amount is negative then Hide **Transfer Button** if the amount is positive then show **Transfer Button**

**HTML**

```
<div class ="content">
         <span class ="negative-account" *ngIf="account?.primaryValue! <= 0">-</span>
              <span class="dollar-sign">$</span>
                    {{account?.primaryValue | currency: '': '' | absolute }}
</div>
<div class="transfer"
     *ngIf="showTransferLink"
   <div> Transfer</div>
</div>
```

**Typescript**

```
export class AccountComponent {
private _showTransferLink = false;

@Input ()
public set showTransferLink(showTransferLink: boolean) {
    this._showTransferLink = attributeToBoolean(showTransferLink);
}

public get showTransferLink() {
return (
  this._showTransferLink &&
  this.account
);
}
```

Comment: Could you please provide the HTML for the Transfer button as well to see what you currently have?

Comment: Where is transfer button ?

Comment: I have added the transfer Button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that you already show or hide a minus based on the value of the account.  Why not apply the same logic to the button?

```
<div class="transfer" *ngIf="account?.primaryValue >= 0">
   <div>Transfer</div>
</div>
```

This should show or hide the button if the `primaryValue` of the account is less or more than 0